# ¿Como ver la versión de lenguaje kotlin y java de un nuevo proyecto android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

estoy trabajando con un nuevo proyecto de android y quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de ver que versión de los lenguajes kotlin y java utiliza el proyecto. Dentro del archivo build.graddle.app encontre esto:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'
```

pero no estoy seguro si esa es la versión de kotlin con la que está trabajando ¿Existe alguna forma de verificar esos datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes verla desde el menú, `File` -> `Project Structure...`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en realidad es el mismo valor que mencionas y que se encuentra definido dentro del archivo `build.gradle`:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
```